# Segue from cell and parse object not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a table view and when clicking on a button I want to switch scenes and parse an object with it.

My code looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedPreset = presets[indexPath.row]

    let destinationVC = Display_ExercisePreset_ViewController()
    destinationVC.preset = selectedPreset

    destinationVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayPreset", sender: self)
}
```

I get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<TrainingsLog.Display_ExercisePreset_ViewController: 0x7fe2716243b0>) has no segue with identifier 'displayPreset''

This obviously says that my destination ViewController doesn't have a segue. I thought I have to make a segue from my starting VC to my destination VC and name it. This is what I have done. `[self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayPreset", sender: self)]` also works.

Answer (score 0):

1-

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayPreset", sender: selectedPreset)
```

2-

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "displayPreset" , 
       let nextScene = segue.destination as! nextVC {
           nextScene.displayPreset = sender as! typeOfDisplayPreset
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: With this code I get the syntax error: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Display_ExercisePreset_ViewController'`

Answer (score -1):

If anyone cares, here is the code that worked for me:

```
var selectedPreset : ExercisePreset?; 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedPreset = presets[indexPath.row]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayPreset", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "displayPreset") {
        var nextScene = segue.destination as! Display_ExercisePreset_ViewController
        nextScene.preset = selectedPreset;
    }
}
```

Not very beautiful because I use a globale variable for the selected Preset but I could find a better solution that worked